# Looking for an obscure movie about time travel

Tags: story-identification, movie

Years ago, I saw a time traveling movie, in the movie people go back hundreds of thousands of years, there are aliens involved, I think they can see into the past at one point on some kind of screen.  The aliens were in the past on earth doing something or other.  I think the movie was titled something like 20,000,000 years something or other. Its at least thirty years old.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_Million_BC - Dinosaurs, not aliens.

Comment: @Richard but that's clearly not thirty years old...

Comment: how about 5 Million years to Earth? It's from the 70's; link: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062168/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_19

Comment: one other possibility is Time Tunnel from 1967. It was a TV show that was later turned into movies: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Tunnel

Comment: @djm - That could be it too, it's also known as "Quatermass and the Pit". Some spoilers here: they don't actually travel back in time, but there is a scene where they're able to project images from someone's subconscious mind onto a screen, and it turns out to be a kind of race memory of aliens that used to live on Mars millions of years ago, embedded in the human subconscious for reasons explained in the movie.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [Journey to the Center of Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_Center_of_Time)? According to Wikipedia it involves time travel to both the future and the prehistoric past, aliens trying to colonize the Earth. The full movie is on DailyMotion, the scene from about 8:00-9:00 shows they do have a giant screen which they can set to show past times:

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x230k10_journey-to-the-center-of-time-1967_shortfilms

Also, this movie was a remake of the earlier movie [The Time Travelers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Travelers_(1964_film)), although that one didn't feature aliens or a trip to the past.

Comment: see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76770/movie-id-50s-60s-time-travel-film-with-terrible-plot-holes for more details on the plot of this film